# Java 8 - collect List attributes with Set<?> type as a set of values

Tags: java, java-8

I have a `List<Entity> entites;` where Entity has fields called testField with Set type:

```
class Entity {
    Set<String> testField;
}
```

I want to get all String that are contained in all testField Sets within entites list; So if I wouldn't use java 8 my code woud look lile:

```
Set<String> allTestFieldString = newHashSet();
for(Entity entity : entities) {
    allTestFieldString.addAll(entity.testField);
}
```

The following code doesn't compile for me:

```
entites.stream().map(entity -> entity.testField()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Would appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `flatMap` to produce a Stream of all the elements of all the `testField` Sets :

```
Set<String> allTestFieldString = entites.stream().flatMap(entity -> entity.testField.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet())
```